# How does this proof assume the existence of an inverse?

Tags: linear-model, linear

I am reading the proof of theorem 2 here https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03610926.2016.1183786

Part of this proof says that

If $AX \perp BX$ then $AX \perp f_B(BX) = X^T BB^- BX = X^T B X$

I understand that if $X \perp Y$ then $X \perp G(Y)$ for any function $G$. But it seems to me the author is assuming that an inverse $B^-$ exists, when in reality there is no guarantee of such.

The assumptions the author makes is:

1. $A$ and $B$ are real matrices
2. $A$ and $B$ are symmetric
3. $\Sigma = E[X^T X]$ is positive semi definite

I struggle to see how any of these guarantee the existence of an inverse?

Comment: Is there any possiblity if it's [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse)?

Comment: The proof should still work (if I understand generalised inverse definition correctly)... But do any of the above statement imply the existence of a generalised inverse?

Comment: This page https://www.alexejgossmann.com/generalized_inverse/ seems to imply every symmetric matrix has a generalised inverse so I'm guessing the above statement is correct?

Comment: This [article](https://www.stt.msu.edu/users/pszhong/Generalized-Inverse-and-Projectors-C.R.Rao_Book_Appendix.pdf) said, it always exists.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Changing the notation might clarify what the statement is really saying.  It asserts that for any symmetric real matrix $B,$ there exists a real matrix $C$ (not necessarily unique) for which $BCB=B.$  It should now be evident that $C$ is not necessarily an inverse of $B$ (although if $B$ does have an inverse, it will serve).  The relation $BCB=B$ (which has nothing to do with $X$) implies $X^\prime B X$ is a function of $BX$ alone.  The existence of such a $C$ is geometrically obvious; presumably the references provide algebraic demonstrations of this fact.